# Convert string as hex to hexadecimal

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have a function that takes an `uint64_t` variable. Normally I would do this:

```
irsend.sendNEC(result.value);
```

`result.value` is an uint64_t as hexadecimal (I think). If I do this:

```
String((uint32_t) results.value, HEX)
```

I get this:

```
FF02FD
```

If I do:

```
irsend.sendNEC(0x00FF02FD)
```

it works perfectly and is what I want.

Instead of grabbing the `result.value`, I want to write it as a string (because that's what I get from the GET request). How do I make `"FF02FD"` into `0x00FF02FD`?

EDIT:

Maybe this makes it easier to understand:

```
GET: http://192.168.1.125/code=FF02FD

//Arduino grabs the FF02FD by doing:

for (int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
  if (server.argName(i) == "code") {
    String code = server.arg(i);
    irsend.sendNEC(code);
  }
}
```

This is where I get the error:

> no matching function for call to 'IRsend::sendNEC(String&)'

because:

```
void sendNEC(uint64_t data, uint16_t nbits = NEC_BITS, uint16_t repeat = 0);
```

Comment: You want the C answer or the Arduino answer?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Uh, Arduino. Wouldn't they be the same or?

Comment: Arduino is not C. It's a crazy mix of C and C++ and some stupid compiling rules. In C use `strtoll`.

Comment: `irsend.sendNEC(0x00FF02FD)` is taking a hard coded value which is fixed at compile time and is no different from `irsend.sendNEC(0xFF02FD)`. What has a string to do with it?

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem is, the Arduino gets a GET request, which has the "FF02FD" as an argument. I need to parse that argument to `sendNEC()`.

Comment: Updated with better explanation.

Comment: You could have a look at [strtoul](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1.aspx) or [strtoull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320173.aspx).

Comment: @WeatherVane Already tried: `cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long unsigned int strtoul(const char*, char**, int)'`

Comment: Use it in conjunction with `String.toCharArray` or `c_str`. That's why I told you it's a crazy mix of stuff...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Arduino is C++ **based**, but not exactly C++ (it uses a modified C++ compiler, gcc IIRC, but it could be clang). It is definitively not C based.

Comment: Build the number from the hex string directly yourself, only slightly harder (because of the discontinuity between `9` and `A`, and variable case) than a decimal string. `value = value * 16 + thisdigit`.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Ardunino is **not** C! See ^

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you give me an example?

Comment: See `https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=311875.0`. Call the `StrToHex` with `someString.c_str()`, where `someString` is of type `String` You may also want to change the return value of the function to your desired `uint64_t`, as `int` is a 16-bit integer on Arduino. Remember, Your Arduino Nano/Uno is a 8-bit microcontroller. It actually impresses me that somebody wrote code that uses 64-bit ints.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]` when I do `irsend.sendNEC(StrToHex(code.c_str()))` - Also, this is an ESP8266, but yes :)

Comment: Then change argument signature to `const char* str`. (edit: okay, on the 32-bit ESP8266 xtensa-tensilica core, 64-bit is okay.)

Comment: Looks like it worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment writeup:

As already suggested, a string containing a hexadecimal value can be converted to an actual integer value using the C standard library functions such as "string to unsigned long" (`strtoul`) or "string to unsigned long long" (`strtoull`). From Arduino-type `String` one can get the actual `const char*` to the data using the `c_str()` member function. All in all, one does a hex-string to integer conversion as

```
uint64_t StrToHex(const char* str)
{
  return (uint64_t) strtoull(str, 0, 16);
}
```

Which can then in code be called as

```
for (int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
  if (server.argName(i) == "code") {
    String code = server.arg(i);
    irsend.sendNEC(StrToHex(code.c_str()));
  }
}
```

Appendum: Be carefull about using `int` or `long` on different platforms. On a Arduino Uno/Nano with a 8-bit microcontroller, such as the ATMega328P, an `int` is a `int16_t`. On the 32-bit ESP8266 CPU, an `int` is `int32_t`.