# C# inputting string for Arduino ir send(irremote)

Tags: c#, arduino

I am a newbie to the Arduino and this web page so please be understanding and sorry my bad English. I hope I have written down things clearly.

I get this error `IRsend::sendNEC(String&, int)` when I trying this command: `irsend.sendNEC(String, 32)`. I tried to convert int but I it makes more errors.

Here my C# code:

```
 serialPort = new SerialPort("COM9", 115200);
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort.DtrEnable = false;
        serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort.Open();
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SignalReceived);

private void SignalReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            string indata = serialPort.ReadExisting();

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if(indata != null | indata != "")
            textBox1.AppendText(indata + Environment.NewLine);
        });
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort.Write("0xFF1AE5");
    }
```

I tried serialPort write to int:

```
int MyInt = 0xFF1AE5;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);
serialPort.Write(b,0,4);
```

Here my arduino code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
String str = Serial.readString();
unsigned long cmdlong = str.toInt();
irsend.sendNEC(cmdlong, 32);
Serial.println(cmdlong);
```

output is will be nothing.
I tried convert char too but not differently.

```
char inData[str.length() + 1];
str.toCharArray(inData, str.length() + 1);
irsend.sendNEC(inData, 32);
```

Thank you for all the ideas!

Comment: From the incomplete error message, it looks like `IRsend::sendNEC(String&, int)` expects a `String&` but you are passing `long`. Just try `irsend.sendNEC(str, str.length());`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the reply. I tried your code and ir led flashes one times but doesn't work, arduino is not catch exception. Here the code: irsend.sendNEC(str[str.length()], 32);

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683071/convert-string-as-hex-to-hexadecimal

Comment: Thanks ,I found another way:

String str = Serial.readString();
const char* string1 = str.c_str();
unsigned long int w = strtoul(string1, NULL, 16);
irsend.sendNEC(w, 32);